# Make child element of Link not route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

- I'm coding an application where people can make posts, and comment on them.
- All of the posts are displayed on one page.
- If a post is clicked the user gets routed to that post's page, which contains the full post, more details, and all of that post's comments.
- Currently, I have the post div wrapped in a react-router Link. That works swell, except that when I click a button inside that div, I still get routed.
- I want everywhere in the div to be "clickable", except actions like other Links or buttons.

```
<Link to={`/${_id}`}>
        <div>
            <button>I don't want this button to route</button>
        </div>
</Link>
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this, but I can't find anything on it. I found one guy on another forum asking the same thing, but it was old and never got answered. Maybe I'm missing it, but I can't find it in the react-router docs. Maybe react-router is not even capable of this, idk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like a quickfix but I don't know if its the best way to address this. I am looking first at the useRef but no avail.

Using something like e.preventDefault on the onClicks will probably save a lot of headache

```
    <Link to="/">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <button onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>HAIYAAA</button>
    </Link>
```

On hindsight this seems to be a Event Bubbling Issue right there.

See a fiddle here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-5rj2b?file=/index.js

EDIT:
Probably a much more dynamic way is to add a condition at the Link's OnClick and exclude the nested A (don't nest it otherwise React will nag you about it) and Button.
Basically we are dealing with a event bubbling here so might just use it to fine grain the behavior that we want. clicking anywhere inside the div will result to being routed to a page, while clicking any A or Button will not

```
  <Link
    to="/"
    onClick={(e) => {
      if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        if (["A", "BUTTON"].includes(e.target.nodeName)) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    }}
  >
    <div>
      Home
      <br />
      <button}>
        HAIYAAA Don't Route me
      </button>
      <br />
      <a href="#">
        This is a link that is nested (Its not good to nest a!)
      </a>
    </div>
  </Link>
```

Fiddle here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-4m4ww?file=/index.js

PS : ahh I spent time to learn something. Thanks for making my afternoon not a sleepy one

Comment: e.preventDefault() was all I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

We need to stop the propagation of `onClick` event of the child to its parent.

```
<Link to="/">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <button onClick={(e) => {
        myNeededBehaviour();
        e.stopPropagation();
     }}>
        HAIYAAA
    </button>
 </Link>
```

so, the stopPropagation will stop the event from propagating to its parent, and it will still calls `myNeededBehaviour();` if you want, but the parent wont get the child's event. so it wont route, as it is not getting triggered.

Comment: e.stopPropagation() did not work for me, but I e.preventDefault() worked. Haven't tested other links, just a button.